# Mongoose storing model in the wrong collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been working at this bug for a couple hours now but I'm at a loss at what is going on.

I'm using mongoose to define a model in the following manner:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var soilSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    fertility: Number,
    waterRetention: Number,
}, { collection: 'soils' });

var Soil = mongoose.model('Soil', soilSchema);
module.exports = Soil;
```

I have another function that's called seedSoil that I use to seed some initial data:

```
Soil = require('../soil.js');

exports.seedSoil = function(){
    Soil.find(function(err, soils){
        if(soils.length){
            console.log('Some soils already exist, not seeding');
            return;
        }

        console.log('Seeding with base soils');
        new Soil({
            name: 'Fertile Soil',
            fertility: .90,
            waterRetention: .60,
        }).save();

        new Soil({
            name: 'Loamy Soil',
            fertility: .6,
            waterRetention: .80,
        }).save();

        new Soil({
            name: 'Sandy Soil',
            fertility: .4,
            waterRetention: .2,
        }).save();
    });
}
```

So the problem is that the code is trying to put the above data into a collection called users and with the schema of another collection I defined in another file. I cannot figure out why it is doing this unfortunately..

I can show you the code in my main express js file as well, just in case:  I just cannot figure out where the user  model is getting shoved in front.  I can post the user class if necessary as well.

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    jquery = require('jquery');

var message = require('./lib/random_message.js'),
    credentials = require('./credentials.js'),
    starter_soils = require('./models/seed_data/starter_soils.js');

var app = express();

require('./lib/passport.js')(passport); // pass passport for configuration


var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars').create({ 
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    helpers: {
        static: function(name) {
            return require('./lib/static.js').map(name);
        },
        json: function(context) {
            return JSON.stringify(context);
        }
    }
});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//set up logging

switch(app.get('env')){
    case 'development':
        app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
        break;
    case 'production':
        app.use(require('express-logger')({
            path: __dirname + '/log/requests.log'
        }));
        break;
}

// set up page testing
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    //console.log(res.req.query);
    res.locals.showTests = app.get('env') !== 'production' && res.req.query.test === '1';
    next();
});

// set up mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var opts = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 }
    }
};
switch(app.get('env')){
    case 'development':
        mongoose.connect(credentials.mongo.development.connectionString, opts);
        break;
    case 'production':
        mongoose.connect(credentials.mongo.production.connectionString, opts);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error('Unknown execution environment: ' + app.get('env'));
}

starter_soils.seedSoil();
```

EDIT: Added the user class as requested

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    joinDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    version: Number,
    lastAction: Date,
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(

password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(SALT_WORK_FACTOR), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Can you share starter_soils.js , also are you sure your seedSoil function works correctly and by the way you have users collection, have you ever call any save method for users collection?

Comment: starter_soils.js is the second snippet of code I posted there.  And in terms of your second question, what do you mean by that? as far as I know, I don't think I am, but I must be missing something somewhere

Comment: as you said you have an user model , so where is the saving process about it, may be there is a mistake. It seems impossible to save another collection with these code blocks .

Comment: I see, I just added it! Does anything look off to you?

Comment: Ok, I added a hook into the user class with pre('save'), and its saving through the user class for some unknown reason.. it must be calling it but I'm not exactly sure why

Comment: Is `Soil = require('../soil.js');` intentionally global? Does adding a `var` in front fix that? If you have a bad assignment somewhere else `Soil` could actually be something else. So it might be worth inspecting `Soil` before the seed data is inserted.